# How to use value from two different rows of a table in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with the following structure and data:

```
Increments

id   emp_id     starting_salary    increment_rate   increment_frequency
2     340            5000                250                  1
3     340            5000                250                  4
```

I need to have aliases, `a` and `b` which will hold some value based on the following formula:

```
starting_salary + (increment_rate * increment_frequency)
```

To be precise, I want `a = 5250` (based on `a = (5000 + (250 * 1))`) and `b = 6000` (based on `b = (5000 + (250 * 4))`)

Now I have another table with the following data:

```
 PaySlips

   id        employee_id       salary_month             arrear
  173824         340           '2015-06-01'              2350
```

I want to join `a` and `b` that I got from the table `Increments` with table `PaySlips`. And I want to use `a` and `b` in the following way:

```
((a * 8) / 30 + (b * 22) / 30)
```

My alias will be `basic_salary`. So `basic_salary` will hold this value from the above calculation:

```
basic_salary = ((a * 8) / 30 + (b * 22) / 30) 
= ((5250 * 8) / 30 + (6000 *22) / 30) 
= (1400 + 4400) 
= 5800
```

I've got no idea how to do this.  Can anyone please help me?

All I got are the common columns in both tables - `emp_id` and `employee_id` and I can join both tables using these columns. I just can't figure out how I can store the above values and organize the calculation inside my query.

Sample query:

```
SELECT x.id, x.employee_id, 
(*my calculation using a and b from table Increments*) AS basic_salary,
x.salary_month, x.arrear
FROM PaySlips x
JOIN Increments y
ON x.employee_id = y.emp_id
```

For determining `a`:

```
SELECT 
(
starting_salary + 
(increment_rate * increment_frequency)
) AS a
FROM Increments
WHERE id = 2
```

And for determining `b`:

```
SELECT 
(
starting_salary + 
(increment_rate * increment_frequency)
) AS b
FROM Increments
WHERE id = 3
```

MySQL version: 5.2

Comment: How do you determine which row is 'a' and which row is 'b'??

Comment: `a` has `id = 2` and `b` has `id = 3` of table `Increments`. Check my update.

Comment: to determine a and b, do you want to use min and max of increment_frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear on all the details, for example what should happen if there are three rows for one employee in increments? Anyhow, here's a sketch to start with:

```
select employee_id
     , ((a * 8) / 30 + (b * 22) / 30) as basic_salary 
from (
    select x.employee_id
         , min(starting_salary + (increment_rate * increment_frequency)) as a
         , max(starting_salary + (increment_rate * increment_frequency)) as b
         , x.salary_month, x.arrear 
    from payslips x 
    join increments y 
        on x.employee_id = y.emp_id 
    group by x.employee_id, x.salary_month, x.arrear
) as t
```

If id 2 and 3 are the criteria (I assumed they are examples) you can use a case statement like:

```
 select employee_id
      , ((a * 8) / 30 + (b * 22) / 30) as basic_salary 
 from (
     select x.employee_id
          , max(starting_salary + (increment_rate * case when y.id = 2 then increment_frequency end )) as a
          , max(starting_salary + (increment_rate * case when y.id = 3 then increment_frequency end)) as b
          , x.salary_month
          , x.arrear 
     from payslips x 
     join increments y 
         on x.employee_id = y.emp_id 
     group by x.employee_id, x.salary_month, x.arrear
) as t;
```

In this case it does not matter what aggregate you use, it is to get rid of the row that contains null.

Answer (score 1):

based on the requirements you added i think something like this will solve your problems:

```
SELECT  PS.id, PS.employee_id, ((A.value * 8) / 30 + (B.value * 22) / 30) AS basic_salary
FROM    PaySlips AS PS
        JOIN (
                    SELECT I.emp_id, I.starting_salary + (increment_rate * increment_frequency) AS VALUE
                    FROM   Increments AS I
                    WHERE  I.id = 2
                ) AS A 
            ON A.emp_id = PS.employee_id
        JOIN (
                    SELECT I.emp_id, I.starting_salary + (increment_rate * increment_frequency) AS value
                    FROM   Increments AS I
                    WHERE  I.id = 3
                ) AS B 
            ON B.emp_id = PS.employee_id
```

This version might need some alteration if it's not working on your real scenario, but please feel free to tell if anything else needs amending.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For determining and setting @a variable:

```
SET @a := (SELECT 
(
starting_salary + 
(increment_rate * increment_frequency)
) AS a
FROM Increments
WHERE id = 2);
```

And for determining and setting @b variable:

```
SET @b := (SELECT 
(
starting_salary + 
(increment_rate * increment_frequency)
) AS b
FROM Increments
WHERE id = 3);
```

Then you can use **@a** and **@b** in your main query;
you can test simply by

```
SELECT @a as a;
SELECT @b as b;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    x.id, 
    x.employee_id,
    (y.a * 8) / 30 + (y.b * 22) / 30 as basic_salary,
    x.salary_month, 
    x.arrear
FROM PaySlips x
JOIN (
    select t1.emp_id, t1.a, t2.b
    from (
        select 
        emp_id,
        starting_salary + increment_rate * increment_frequency as a
        from Increments
        where id = 2
    ) as t1
    join (
        select 
        emp_id,
        starting_salary + increment_rate * increment_frequency as b
        from Increments
        where id = 3
    ) as t2
    on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
) as y
ON x.employee_id = y.emp_id
```